# AWS-Appsync How to query latest items from the dynamoDB table?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-appsync

I have just gotten started with AWS Appsync and have gone through most of the tutorial (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/api) using the GraphQL and SDK methods mostly.

How do I query my dynamoDB table to only return the latest 50 articles?

```
class TestScreen extends Component {
    state = { list: [] }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const fetched = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listArticles))
        this.setState({ 
            list: fetched.data.listArticles.items,
        })
    }

    renderRow(item) {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.list}
                    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderRow(item)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Currently the query returns me the list of names but not in any identifiable order.

Comment: Questions should be specific and answerable. "Is there a good place to start" is too broad and will lead to opinions instead of good answers.  To improve this question show us what you have done. Show source code and describe what it is doing and what you need it to do. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) on a timestamp field and use it to query the table. In addition to that, you can also do [pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/designing-your-schema.html#advanced-relations-and-pagination).